# Why aren't javax.script classes recognized by Java15?

Tags: java

I am trying to import scrip engine related classes and using Java 15 oracle standard on windows 10 in eclipse.

```java
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

Compiler says - "The type javax.script.ScriptEngineManager is not accessible"

Comment: Does your app's module declare that it depends on `java.scripting`?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages.  Don't do it at all.  Also, please post the actual compilation error messages ... not just the lines where the errors occur.  (Hint: we can't "hover" over those lines to see what your IDE tells you the problem is.)

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of snapshot restrictions. I'll edit to include lines of compiler complaints.

Comment: yeah module dependency was a problem and I did not know about it

Comment: Yea.  If you are using Java 9 or later, Java modules are a thing you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using Eclipse.

If you place the cursor on the red-underlined text and press Ctrl+1 (Quick Fix), or right-click and select "Quick Fix", you get a pop-up menu like this:

[image: pop-up menu]

Select the menu item highlighted here to add the missing `requires` statement to the `module-info.java` file.

It doesn't matter which of the 3 lines you do this on.

Answer (score 0):

If your Editor does not supply you with helpful quick fixes, you will have to:

1. enter the "module-info.java"
2. paste "requires java.scripting;" beneath the other requires
3. Save and done

I personally was using visual studio code and it did not supply me any helpful quick fixes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).